# kernel.log stays empty: “rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): Operation not permitted.”

Tags: rsyslog

I'm on a VPS (Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, Kernel 3.13.0-042stab094.8, rsyslog 7.4.4-1ubuntu2.5) and kernel.log stays empty with only this line:

```
rsyslogd: imklog: cannot open kernel log (/proc/kmsg): Operation not permitted.
```

The server was preconfigured with syslogd and klogd from busybox. I deinstalled them and installed rsyslog with apt-get. Everything seemed to work fine. I have entries in all the other logfiles.

I'm not sure if it is relatet to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rsyslog/+bug/1366829

Answer (score 6):

I think the VPS is not a VM, but a container. Unpriviledged cotainers do not have access to kernel log for security reasons.

Comment: you're right, the container needs to run with `--privileged`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need or have insufficient system access to read the kernel log, you can remove the `imklog` module (which is what attempts to read it)

```
-module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
+# module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support
```

[This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60265997/4541045) for the same issue under Docker suggests the following command, which can be incorporated into scripts

```
sed -i '/imklog/s/^/#/' /etc/rsyslog.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading from `/proc/kmsg` require superuser permissions. Did you start rsyslogd as root?

If so, please run the command `ls -al /proc/kmsg` and paste here the output.

Comment: /proc/kmsg is owned by (root:root). But what troubles me is, that kernel logginging to kernel.log should work, even when rsyslogd drops privileges, like a ubuntu default installation. I wonder how this is solved.

Comment: `/var/log/kernel.log` can very well be root-only writable. This means that if rsyslogd runs with lower privileges, it could not write to it. With which user run your rsyslogd instance? Can you provide `ls -al /proc/ksmg`, `ls -al /var/log/kernel.log` and `ps ax | grep rsyslog`?

Comment: $ ls -al /proc/kmsg
-r-------- 1 root root 0 May 11 08:37 /proc/kmsg
$ ls -al /var/log/kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 115 May 11 08:37 /var/log/kern.log
$ ps auxw | grep rsyslog
syslog     332  0.0  0.1 186352 14640 ?        Ssl  May11   0:07 rsyslogd

So kern.log is writeable for rsyslog, but /proc/kmsg is not readable. The question is, how does ubuntu solves this in a default installation?

Comment: On my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, permissions are precisely as on your machine. Basically, rsyslogd start as root and opens /proc/kmsg, then it drops privileges. It seems that some kernel/rsyslogd combination have problems with the privilege dropping (eg: [read here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+source/rsyslog/+bug/523610). You can try to disable the privilege-dropping feature: edit `/etc/rsyslog.conf` and comments the lines with `$PrivDropToUser syslog` and `$PrivDropToGroup syslog`, then restart rsyslogd.